# Time trend analyses using "years vs continuous var" ecological data?

Tags: r

Looking at my time trend plot, I wonder how to test the statistical significance in the trend shown here given this simple "years vs rate" ecological data, using R? I tried ANOVA turned in p<0.05 treating year variable as a factor. But I'm not satisfied with ANOVA. Also, the article I reviewed suggested Wald statistics to test the time trend. But I found no guiding examples in Google yet.

My data:

```
> head(yrrace)
  year racecat rate outcome      pop
1 1995       1 14.2    1585 11170482
2 1995       2  8.7     268  3070363
3 1996       1 14.1    1574 11170482
4 1996       2  7.5     230  3070363
5 1997       1 13.3    1482 11170482
6 1997       2  8.3     254  3070363
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the code for the model you are using. Might be better to ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not modelling yet. Thanks for suggestion. I just posted my question at stats.stackexchange.